# apply multiple vector to function

Tags: kdb

I have a simple function which returns a table:

```
F[("A";"B");(1,-1)]
```

I would like to apply this function passing vectors as inputs:

```
a:((`A;`B);(`B;`C);(`C;`D))
b:((1;-1);(1;-1);(1;-1))
```

I have tried:

```
F each a,b
F each a cross b
```

but this doesn't work or combines the vectors rather than keeping the 2 components separate. In addition when I do get it to work how do I row bind the resulting list of tables? I am coming from a python background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `'` each-both :

```
q)F:{ ([] enlist x; enlist y)}    /if F is simply creating a table 

q)F[("A";"B");(1,-1)]
x    y
---------
"AB" 1 -1

q)a:((`A;`B);(`B;`C);(`C;`D))
q)b:((1;-1);(1;-1);(1;-1))

q)F'[a;b]   /each-both
+`x`y!(,`A`B;,1 -1)
+`x`y!(,`B`C;,1 -1)
+`x`y!(,`C`D;,1 -1)
```

`raze` will format it to a table (i think row binding means appending the tables together)

```
q)raze F'[a;b]
x   y
--------
A B 1 -1
B C 1 -1
C D 1 -1
```

Comment: Perfect. If there is overlap on the row Dates raze seems to overwrite with latest ones is there a function that allows for duplicated dates on the merged list of tables?

Comment: is it a keyed table are you getting back from `F`?

Comment: try this `raze 0!/:F'[a;b]`